# EC2 Micro Instance - enough memory to run Windows Server 2008 and SQL Server?

Tags: amazon-ec2

The title pretty much says it. Can a micro instance (which only has 613MB of RAM) run Windows Server 2008 and SQL Server without running out of memory? My company wants to use EC2 to host our site, but we want to keep costs low during development.

Comment: Truth is even the small EC2 instance is barely useful for Windows these days.  If you want cheap, don't use EC2.  GoGrid (www.gogrid.com) is a bit more cost effective for Windows servers but still not really cheap.  If you want cheap, use shared hosting somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

I think Windows Micro (613MB RAM) instances are great for their true cloud purposes: namely on-demand access to compute power for transient activities, such as training environments or basic dev/playground/lab activities. For running an actual website, with real clients and potentially some load, you really can't go less than a small instance size. Costs aren't too bad if you buy a Small Reserved Instance, but don't go too cheap and try to use the Micro in production.